# Join table on Sequelize CLI

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am creating an application, and I would like to have more information
about creating a join table.

I have a table media:

```
var Media = sequelize.define('Media', {
    m_title: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    m_duration: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    m_year: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    m_country: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    m_season: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    m_order: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    m_fk_id_type_media: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
```

And Celebrity:

```
var Celebrity = sequelize.define('Celebrity', {
        c_lastname: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        c_firstname: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        c_birth_date: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        c_nationality: DataTypes.STRING(50)
    },
```

Do I have to create the model myself (media_has_celebrities)? Because I tried to add

```
Media.associate = function (models) {
    models.Media.belongsToMany(models.Celebrity, {through: 'MediaHasCelebrity'});
  };
```

and

```
Celebrity.associate = function (models) {
        models.Celebrity.belongsToMany(models.Media, {through: 'MediaHasCelebrity'});
    };
```

but it does not create the model of join as indicated in the documentation?
Do you have to define foreign keys before?

The goal would be to do something like Media.addCelebrity ...

Sorry for my english !

Thank you

Comment: are you using `sequelize.sync({ force: true })`?

Comment: Nop, but I'm not sure, I'm using Sequelize CLI I don't not know if it's included
 : /

Comment: sequelize will only create the new tables if `sequelize.sync({ force: true })` . Be aware that it would drop and recreate all the tables. If you are using cli, you would have to create tables on your own via migrations

Comment: Yes I created my main tables manually, but I don't know if by combining belongsToMany, sequelize will automatically create the tables of joins ? (example: MediaHasCelebries table)

Comment: it will not create table automatically

Comment: But it will create the link between the tables? In the Background